# Clearing Power Pivot Slicers

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot, slicers

does anyone know a good way of clearing the slicers in a workbook.
I have a sheet with many slicers and I would like to have a single button to clear them.

I wrote a bit of VBA to do it **but it’s a little slow** :

```
Sub ClearSlicers()
  Dim cache As SlicerCache

  For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
           cache.ClearManualFilter
  Next cache
End Sub
```

Just wondered if you have anything a little slicker ?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

This will clear all slicers in a sheet

```
Sub test()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cache As Slicer

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    For Each cache In pt.Slicers
        cache.SlicerCache.ClearAllFilters
    Next cache
Next pt

End Sub
```

Comment: That code doesn't work as they are PowerPivot slicers not Pivot Tables. The code I wrote works but takes around 25 secs to complete. I think this is because the data model is refreshing after each filter is cleared. Do you know a way to stop this refresh ? its driving me crazy ;-)